# Are Gemini Harmonie tiles and Gemini Ceramic Pool tiles safe to use for an outdoor mosaic?

Tags: tile, outdoor, materials, ceramic-tile, mosaic

Are [Gemini](http://www.geminitiles.co.uk/default.aspx) Harmonie tiles and Gemini Ceramic Pool tiles safe to use for an outdoor mosaic?
I can't find much information about them online.

Comment: Have you tried [contacting the company](http://www.geminitiles.co.uk/contacts.aspx) directly?

Comment: Glass tile and porcelain are appropriate for outdoor use.  Be sure to use a top rated thin set mortar that lists flexibility (due to thermal expansion/contraction stresses) as an attribute.